# How do I choose to display specific columns of a variable in R (plotly)?

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-plotly

Hey guys I'm new to R and don't understand how to display specific named columns from the dataset within my `plotly` scatter plot, and how to create a line of best fit for those points. 
I have graphed the date vs Enterococci (cfu/100ml), where it displays all the beaches under the variable "Site" with different colours, but I want to be able to choose specific beaches out of this list and add lines of best fit.
I have looked on the internet for hours with no luck on how to do this.
This linked image shows the first few rows of the data where there are also multiple "Sites" not just "Avalon Beach" which is shown

[image: Fig1]

Below is the current chunk of code I have in R and help would be appreciated.
[Link to the data set](https://www.maths.usyd.edu.au/u/UG/JM/MATH1005/r/current/projects/beaches.csv).

```
MN<- read.csv("~/Desktop/beaches.csv", header = TRUE)
MNd <- as.Date(MN$Date, "%d/%m/%y")
MNe <- MN$Enterococci..cfu.100ml.
p4 = plot_ly(MN, x = ~MNd, y = ~MNe, color = ~factor(Site), type="scatter") %>%
  layout(title="Enterococci Levels of beaches in the Northern Beaches Council", 
        xaxis=list(title="Date"), yaxis=list(title="Enterococci (cfu/100ml)"))
p4
```

Comment: Hi Joey, can you provide a link to the dataset itself, not just an image?

Comment: Hey I just provided a link, but I don't know if it would work due to it being provided by my uni and may require you to sign in. Thanks for the help

Comment: Another alternative is to use `dput(head(MN, 20))` and edit your question with the output obtained.

Comment: Why is what I am explaining unachievable in R?

Answer (score 0):

Run this code and tell me what you need.

```
MNd <- as.Date(MN$Date, "%d/%m/%y")
MNe <- MN$Enterococci..cfu.100ml.
ggplot(MN, aes(x=MNd, y=MNe, color=Site))+
  geom_point()+
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

It produces this image
[image]